# apa6: removal of maketitle leads to error

Tags: errors, apa-style, apa6

### Background

I am trying to write a manuscript that has APA6 format citations and bibliography. For this purpose, I am using `\documentclass[man]{apa6}`.

However, I do not want the title page that this class creates by default. In order to achieve it when I commented the `\maketitle`, it led to cascading errors.

### Attempt to address this problem

Instead of commenting the  `\maketitle`, I emptied the fields constituting it such as \title{}, \author{}, \affiliation{} and so on. However, the problem still persists.

### Desired outcome

I want to write a manuscript with apa6 formatting and without a title page

### Code

```
\documentclass[man]{apa6}

\usepackage[american]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa6,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\title{Sample APA-Style Document Using the \textsf{apa6} Package}

\author{Brian D.\ Beitzel}
\affiliation{SUNY Oneonta}

\leftheader{Beitzel}

\abstract{This demonstration paper uses the \textsf{apa6} \LaTeX\
  class to format the document in compliance with the 6th Edition of
  the American Psychological Assocation's \textit{Publication Manual.}
  The references are managed using \textsf{biblatex}.}

\keywords{APA style, demonstration}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

There are some sections in this document following the title.

### Errors

```
Undefined control sequence. \section
Undefined control sequence. \end{document}
Undefined control sequence. \end{document}
Please (re)run Biber on the file:(biblatex) shortsample(biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

### Removing the fields data

```
\documentclass[man]{apa6}

\usepackage[american]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa6,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\title{}

\author{}
\affiliation{}

\leftheader{}

\abstract{}

\keywords{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

### Errors after removing the fields

```
There's no line here to end. \maketitle
There's no line here to end. \maketitle
There's no line here to end. \maketitle
Please (re)run Biber on the file:(biblatex) shortsample(biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

Comment: Hi, There was an answer about apacite, I think that might be useful for me. It has been deleted now. How do get it back?

Comment: Please make sure your example is complete. There is no end document here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the error you get when you comment out the `\maketitle` command, it's an undefined control sequence referring to the `\shorttitle`, which is used in the running head.  So you need to define that in order not to have a title page. (I've removed the bibliography code which is irrelevant here.)

But doing this will fail to create any title at all and won't print the abstract either, since that is produced by the `apa6` `\maketitle` command.

```
\documentclass[man]{apa6}

\usepackage[american]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}


\title{Sample APA-Style Document Using the \textsf{apa6} Package}

\author{Brian D.\ Beitzel}
\affiliation{SUNY Oneonta}
\shorttitle{Short Title}
\leftheader{Beitzel}

\abstract{This demonstration paper uses the \textsf{apa6} \LaTeX\
  class to format the document in compliance with the 6th Edition of
  the American Psychological Assocation's \textit{Publication Manual.}
  The references are managed using \textsf{biblatex}.}

\keywords{APA style, demonstration}

\begin{document}
%\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```